# Get method conflicts not getting resolved in webapi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

My webapi get methods inside MoviesController are

```
// GET api/movies
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the sorted list of movies
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Collection of Movies</returns>
        public IEnumerable<Movie> Get()
        {
            return repository.GetMovies().OrderBy(c => c.Title);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an individual movie
        /// </summary>
        public Movie Get(int movieId)
        {
            var movie = repository.GetMovieById(movieId);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return movie;
        }
```

and WebApiConfig.cs is

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

The problem i am facing is each time Get() is getting called.Get with Id method is not getting called.I have tried various solutions given on SO,but it is not working for me.

Comment: How are you calling method with id ?Post a sample URL ?

Comment: I got the answer,method parameter name is movieId and in webapiconfig its only id.i have changed id with movieid and updated the routetemplate like that      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{movieId}",

Comment: just compare your answer and my answer **routeTemplate**

Comment: By doing this whenever you will call anyother method with same url you will have to give parameter name as movieid.

Comment: Yes i agree with Mairaj..instead of messing up with default route its better to make a custom route as shown in my answer.

Comment: but if i give default movieid 0 it'll throw exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one more **custom route** as shown :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "MyRoute",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{movieId}",
     defaults: new { movieId = "0" }  //instead of default movieid '0' you can specify as per your requirement.
   );
```

Comment: ,then only Get with id is getting called.

Comment: I usually call the Get w/o a parameter GetAll, this is actually a better name in my opinion because it reflects what the method is actually doing. I personally try to avoid messing with routes unless I really have to.

Comment: @mmeasor..if custom routes are made in a proper then it will not create any problem with default route.

Comment: Giving default to zero will thorw exceptions,i have done this    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApiWithMovieId",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{movieId}",
               defaults: new { movieId = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: @little..i think exception is thrown by `Get` method not by route.